# Understanding Pytorch vanilla RNN architectures

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

**Standard interpretation:** in the original RNN, the hidden state and output are calculated as

[image]

In other words, we obtain the the output from the hidden state.

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), the RNN architecture can be unfolded like this:

[image: vani]

And the code I have been using is like:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_dim, 1)   
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)

        out, hidden = self.rnn(x)

        # getting output from the hidden state
        out = out..view(-1, self.hidden_dim)
        out = self.fc(out)

        return out, hidden
```

**RNN as "pure" feed-forward layers:** but today, I see another implementation from the [Pytorch Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html#creating-the-network)

[image]

And their code is like

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden

    def initHidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
```

The hidden layer calculation is same as the standard interpretation, but the output is is calculated independently from the current hidden state `h`.

To me, the math behind this implementation is:

[image]

So, this implementation is different from the original RNN implementation?

I have been using RNN for almost 1 year and I thought I understand it, not until today when I see this post from Pytorch. I am really confused now.

Comment: Good catch! I guess there are two issues here, First it does not introduce a nonlinear transformation while calculating the new hidden state, and 2, it dose not consider the h_t for the calculation of the output!  at least for the elman network, thats how it should have been unless, he is implementing something else!

Comment: I see. I have also checked the source code and create a new issue tagging the original author. I hope he can answer the reason behind this implementation.
https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/issues/566